# Scroll by link to #div with using jquery to smooth scrolling and keep url

Tags: jquery, html

I have one page design with scrolling eased by jquery using this code:

```
function ScrollMe(id){
                var offset = $("#"+id).offset().top-50;
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: offset},'slow');
         };
```

And this html:

```
<a onclick="ScrollMe('about')"  href="javascript:void(0)">About</a>
```

works fine, but what I need is to change href to "#about" so the url would be updated when is clicked on link. I just dont know how to keep easing in that case.

Thanks

EDIT
so for me works good enough this one:

```
 <a href="#contact" onclick="return scrollMe('contact');">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply set `id` of anchor correctly set `href`? Like this, for example:

```
<a href="#about" onclick="scrollMe('about'); return false;">About</a>
```

This correctly sets browser's location, so it can be copied and transfered. But if you want animation to be played when your page is opened from another page, not this, you should call smth like `scrollMe(location.hash)` after page was loaded.

NOTE: `location.hash` might note work on some browsers.

Comment: Only 
<a href="#contact" onclick="return scrollMe('contact');"> works as you had it before

Comment: @user1189382 If you provide some code, I can figure out where the problem is. As for your comment, probably you have some kind of `return false` statement or smth raises an exception in you `scrollMe()` function that stops event propagation, so your code works. And another quesrion: you mean 'works' - scrolls smoothly without immediate jump to the anchor?

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way is to just add return: false; to your onclick:

```
<a onclick="ScrollMe('about');return false;" href="#about">About</a>
```

However, the BETTER way would be to change it as follows:

```
<a class="about" href="#about">About</a>
```

And add this to your javascript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".about").click(
         function() {
             scrollMe('about');
             return false;
         }
    );
});
```

Comment: Maybe, change class-attribute to smth like 'animated'? And extract href from an element itself, rather then hardcode it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#about" onClick="ScrollMe('about'); return false;">About</a>
```

That would do it.